# Why am I getting an attribute error? How can I fix it?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()

X = diabetes.data
y = diabetes.target


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)


mms = MinMaxScaler()
X_train_norm = mms.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_norm = mms.transform(X_test)


stdsc = StandardScaler()
X_train_std = stdsc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_std = stdsc.transform(X_test)


LogisticRegression(penalty='l1')
lr = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', C=1.0, multi_class='auto', solver='liblinear')
lr.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
print('Training accuracy:', lr.score(X_train_std, y_train))
print('Test accuracy:', lr.score(X_test_std, y_test))

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, random_state=1)

forest.fit(X_train, y_train)

importances = forest.feature_importances_

print(importances)

feature_labels = diabetes.columns[0:]

print(feature_labels)
```

This is the error I am getting. Can anyone help?

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in __getattr__(self, key)
     95         try:
---> 96             return self[key]
     97         except KeyError:

KeyError: 'columns'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-163-74a2bb3a96b9> in <module>
      9 print(importances)
     10 
---> 11 feature_labels = diabetes.columns[0:]
     12 print(feature_labels)
     13 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in __getattr__(self, key)
     96             return self[key]
     97         except KeyError:
---> 98             raise AttributeError(key)
     99 
    100     def __setstate__(self, state):

AttributeError: columns
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can print out the columns keys like than print any columns by it's key

```
keys= diabetes.keys()
print(keys)
feature_labels = diabetes["data"]
print(feature_labels)
```

or If you want to loop through the keys you can do something like this

```
for key in diabetes.keys(): 
    print(key)
    feature_labels = diabetes[key ]
    print(feature_labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get features, it's not using a column. You are already define it above

```
X = diabetes.data
```

and as long as i know, built-in dataset doesn't contain any header of each column. you have to define it by yourself. for example using pandas library